# symfony2 Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! with doctrine eventlistener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have eventlistener `preUpdate`

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {        
    $user = $args->getEntity();
    if($user instanceof \iTracker\UserBundle\Entity\User) {
        if($args->hasChangedField('userGroup')) {

            $old = $args->getOldValue('userGroup');
            $new = $args->getNewValue('userGroup');

            $em = $args->getEntityManager();

            $old->setAmount($old->getAmount() - 1);
            $em->persist($old);

            $new->setAmount($new->getAmount() + 1);
            $em->persist($new);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And after submiting form i get `FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6123`

> in /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6123 at
>   ErrorHandler->handleFatal() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php
>   line 0 at NormalizerFormatter->normalize() in
>   /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6198 at
>   LineFormatter->normalize() in /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php
>   line 6112 at NormalizerFormatter->format() in
>   /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6172 at
>   LineFormatter->format() in /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php
>   line 6320 at AbstractProcessingHandler->handle() in
>   /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6646 at
>   Logger->addRecord() in /var/www/issue/app/cache/dev/classes.php line
>   6710 at Logger->debug() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Logger/DbalLogger.php
>   line 72 at DbalLogger->log() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Logger/DbalLogger.php
>   line 50 at DbalLogger->startQuery() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Logging/LoggerChain.php
>   line 50 at LoggerChain->startQuery() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php
>   line 774 at Connection->executeUpdate() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 447 at BasicEntityPersister->_updateTable() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 357 at BasicEntityPersister->update() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 984 at UnitOfWork->executeUpdates() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 317 at UnitOfWork->commit() in
>   /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
>   line 355 at EntityManager->flush() in
>   /var/www/issue/src/iTracker/UserBundle/Listener/UserGroupAmount.php
>   line 41
>   and this

- at UserGroupAmount->preUpdate() in
  /var/www/issue/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.php
  line 61
- at ContainerAwareEventManager->dispatchEvent() in
  /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
  line 980
- at UnitOfWork->executeUpdates() in
  /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
  line 317
- at UnitOfWork->commit() in
  /var/www/issue/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php
  line 355
- at EntityManager->flush() in
  /var/www/issue/src/iTracker/UserBundle/Listener/UserGroupAmount.php
  line 41

and this 5 errors are looped, which cause this exception

Comment: Instead of updating your question to add the solution, write an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `flush` suggested by the author is not a correct solution. It will fire onFLush twice and create unneeded savepoints in transaction.

All additional changes can be scheduled in events using `computeChangeSet`, `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet` and `scheduleExtraUpdate` methods.

In case with a different entity:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {        
    $user = $args->getEntity();
    if($user instanceof \iTracker\UserBundle\Entity\User) {
        if($args->hasChangedField('userGroup')) {
            $old = $args->getOldValue('userGroup');
            $new = $args->getNewValue('userGroup');

            $oldOriginAmount = $old->getAmount();
            $newOriginAmount = $new->getAmount();

            $old->setAmount($old->getAmount() - 1);
            $uow->scheduleExtraUpdate($old, array(
                'amount' => array($oldOriginAmount, $old->getAmount())
            ));

            $new->setAmount($new->getAmount() + 1);
            $uow->scheduleExtraUpdate($new, array(
                'amount' => array($newOriginAmount, $new->getAmount())
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `persist` is not needed (because the associated entites aren't created in any event, they should be already persistent).

Comment: I have cope/paste Your code but. It change object `amount` value but didn't make update to database

Comment: @skowron-line oops, `computeChangeSet` should be used if an entity  wasn't marked for update. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

@meze is right, using *flush* inside the **Flush** events will cause a loop.

But there is a quick workaround that will allow you to do it still:
    $eventManager = $this -> em -> getEventManager();

```
// Remove event, if we call $this->em->flush() now there is no infinite recursion loop!
$eventManager -> removeEventListener('onFlush', $this); 

// ...

// Re-attach since we're done
$eventManager -> addEventListener('onFlush', $this);
```

Seen on: [Doctrine2 Event Listener: persisting in onFlush()  | Benedikt Wolters](http://mightyuhu.github.io/blog/2012/03/27/doctrine2-event-listener-persisting-a-new-entity-in-onflush/)

Comment: Couldn't get your idea to work, kept getting same error message as before