# Symfony2 Doctrine Event Listener preUpdate methodMaximum function nesting level error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

User Password change event can handle with Doctrine preUpdate listener but I can't do another log persist process it causes listener loop so error trace like below:

```
Error: Maximum function nesting level of '5000' reached, aborting! in /var/www/my_project/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Event/LifecycleEventArgs.php line 85
```

My preUpdate listener code like below:

```
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    if (php_sapi_name()!='cli') {

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        // perhaps you only want to act on some "User" entity
        if ($entity instanceof User) {

            if($args->hasChangedField('password')){
                //log as eventlog
                $event = new \My_Project\UserBundle\Entity\EventLog();
                $event->setEventInfo(UserEventLogParams::$PASSWORD_CHANGE);
                $event->setIp($this->container->get('request')->getClientIp());
                $event->setUserId($entity->getId());
                $entityManager->persist($event);

                $entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This problem mensioned there [Adding additional persist calls to preUpdate call in Symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16904462/2438520) but not answered with worked solution.

How can i log (to mysql with Doctrine2 event listener)  password change event?

Can i do this with postUpdate method?

Comment: Best to use the Symfony event system and just send out a CHANGED_PASSWORD event.  A Symfony 2 event listener would then take care of logging it.  You could use the Doctrine event listener as well by adding a custom event.  But preUpdate has many restrictions.

Comment: i am using prePersist, preRemove with Doctrine event listener no problem occured. But, on preUpdate methot have an problem. I can call log function from passwordChange function but i want to clean code.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate "Any calls to EntityManager#persist() or EntityManager#remove(), even in combination with the UnitOfWork API are strongly discouraged and don’t work as expected outside the flush operation."

Comment: ok thanks, i will use different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine Event System documentation.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

> Restrictions for this event:
>
> 1. Changes to associations of the passed entities are not recognized by the flush operation anymore.
> 2. Changes to fields of the passed entities are not recognized by the flush operation anymore, use the computed change-set passed to the event to modify primitive field values, e.g. use `$eventArgs->setNewValue($field, $value);` as in the Alice to Bob example above.
> 3. Any calls to `EntityManager#persist()` or `EntityManager#remove()`, even in combination with the UnitOfWork API are strongly discouraged and don’t work as expected outside the flush operation.

As a solution you can fetch `changeSet` in `preUpdate` but call `EntityManager#persist()` and `EntityManager#flush()` in `postUpdate`.

In additional you will need to use private property of your listener $event to get it in `postUpdate` function.

```
privat $event;

public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
if (php_sapi_name()!='cli') {

    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    // perhaps you only want to act on some "User" entity
    if ($entity instanceof User) {

        if($args->hasChangedField('password')){
            //log as eventlog
            $this->event = new \My_Project\UserBundle\Entity\EventLog();
            $this->event->setEventInfo(UserEventLogParams::$PASSWORD_CHANGE);
            $this->event->setIp($this->container->get('request')->getClientIp());
            $this->event->setUserId($entity->getId());

        }
    }
}
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    $entityManager->persist($this->event);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```