# disable Doctrine entity event

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need create another new Entity in **entity** preFlush event in case when current entity was changed. In preFlush I don't have computed change set, if I trigger compute change set, to avoid infinite loop preFlush listener should be disabled.
How can I do that? Does another solution to know if entity was really changed exists?

Comment: `preFlush` is probably not the way to go in such case (This event is not a lifecycle callback). `preUpdate` sounds more like what you need...

Comment: @Wilt ok, looks like I should use preUpdate, but create new entity there is imposible, any ideas?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16906067/1697459)

Comment: there is no entity postFlush event

Comment: Check [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events): *postFlush - The postFlush event occurs at the end of a flush operation. This event is not a lifecycle callback*